# SQLSRV PHP for SQL Server for is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, sqlsrv

Here is my setup

- Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit
- Apache 2.4.4 64 bit
- PHP 5.4.15 32 bit (64 bit is still experimental), thread safe, VC9 compiler
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client 64-bit
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 and x64

I need to load Microsoft's SQLSRV library.

I have added 'extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' to php.ini and copied 'php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' to the ext folder where PHP is installed.

When I restart apache, I get the following error in my php error log, and SQLSRV is not listed in phpinfo.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php5\ext\php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT
For testing purposes I've just installed PHP 5.5.10 64 bit and VC 2012 but the error remains the same :(

Comment: Just guessing here, but I'm not sure if 32bit application (PHP) can load x64 dll (SQL server).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Wouldn't php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll be 32 bit though? I downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098 and can't see any reference to whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  It would be useful to know WHY then I can provide the information you require.

Comment: It's harsh to have a question down voted, this site would be useless without the questions.  However, it might be because 32-bit TS PHP using the Apache module would not work at all with 64-bit Apache.  You would have to use mod_fcgid with 32-bit PHP NTS, or 32-bit Apache instead of 64-bit.  (I just upvoted your question back to 0!)

Comment: Thanks Rob. Really useful comment and certainly sounds logic.  I'll hopefully give it a try, though I am quite impress with UniServer Zero. It got me up and running very quickly :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if it helps but i used all 32bit on my Windows 7 64bit system

Here is what I used and i can use SQL Server

```
httpd-2.4.6-win32-VC9 //apache 2.4
php-5.4.9-Win32-VC9-x86 //php5
```

inside if my `\php\` folder i have

- php5apache2_4.dll

Inside `\php\ext\` i have

- php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

I added this to the end of php.ini

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

I remember it being a right pain getting it to work but it does now.  If i remember anymore i'll edit my answer

**UPDATE:**

I think this blog post looks familiar on how i got it working

http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html

Comment: Thanks AdRock. I'll have a go with your setup and report back as soon as I can. Maybe 64 bit Apache is where it falls over for me.

Comment: I never managed to get this working. I tried numerous tutorials and forums, so I'm sure this answer is correct. There must be a setting somewhere in my setup that causes an issue. Maybe its Apache 2.4 64bit? I decided to use The Uniform Server http://www.uniformserver.com/ instead. Following the above steps worked perfectly.

Comment: If you are using Apache 64 bit, you currently have 2 ways to load PHP with SQLSRV:

1. Use PHP 5.5 64 bit build and custom php_sqlsrv driver build from robsphp blog pages [link](http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html)

2. Get 32-bit PHP and use Apache's mod_fcgid module.  It allows loading 32-bit cgi modules in 64-bit Apache:  [link](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Running a legacy 5.6 php x64 which needed the interface because of the hard RAM restrictions 32 bits give.

The solution was in the unoffical driver offered by Rob.

https://robsphp.blogspot.nl/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

I tested it out, and it works properly with 5.6.33 x64

Answer (score 3):

currently Microsoft sqldriver only works for 32bit php version.
Here is my steps to install sql drivers.

- install 32 bit wamp server below configuratoin Apache : 2.4.9 MySQL :
  5.6.17 PHP : 5.5.12 PHPMyAdmin : 4.1.14 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 XDebug : 2.2.5 installed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 3.2
  drivers installed odbc driver.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlsrv requires php x86. This message appears when php is 64 bit architecture.